# How to group specific items in a column and calculate the mean

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, pivot-table

I am trying to figure out how to group specific tag names in a column and then to calculate the mean of the raw data that have the same time. My dataframe looks something like this except with 10000+ rows:

```
tag_name time raw_data
happy     5      300
          8      340
angry     5      315
          8      349
sad       5      400
          8      480
etc.
.
.
```

I wish to keep the mean in the dataframe table, but I can't figure out how. I found that I can create a pivot table to calculate the mean, but I can't figure out how to single out the specific tag names I want. Below is what I have so far:

```
output = pd.pivot_table(data=dataset,index=['Timestamp'],columns=['Tag_Name'],values='Raw_Data',aggfunc='mean')
```

I am trying to get one of these outputs when I calculate the average of sad and happy:

```
1. optimal output:
tag_name    time raw_data  sad_happy_avg
happy        5      300     350
             8      340     410
sad          5      400
             8      480
angry        5      315
             8      349

2. alright output:
tag_name   happy   sad  avg
time
5           300    400  350
8           340    480  410
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follows:

- Use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to keep only "happy" and "sad", and apply
  [`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)
  to get the data in the correct shape.
- Next, add a column for the [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) on `axis=1`:

```
res = df[df.tag_name.isin(['happy','sad'])].pivot(index='time', columns='tag_name', 
                                       values='raw_data')
res['avg'] = res.mean(axis=1)

print(res)

tag_name  happy  sad    avg
time                       
5           300  400  350.0
8           340  480  410.0
```

Your "optimal" `output` doesn't seem a very logical way to present/store this data, but you can achieve it as follows:

```
# assuming you have a "standard" index starting `0,1,2` etc. 
df['sad_happy_avg'] = df[df.tag_name.isin(['happy','sad'])]\
    .groupby('time')['raw_data'].mean().reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)

  tag_name  time  raw_data  sad_happy_avg
0    happy     5       300          350.0
1    happy     8       340          410.0
2    angry     5       315            NaN
3    angry     8       349            NaN
4      sad     5       400            NaN
5      sad     8       480            NaN
```

Comment: Is there a way to perform the calculation without filtering out the tag names I do not need? It is a great idea, but I have 100+ tag names I'd have to filter out

Comment: But you want only the tags `happy` and `sad`, right? I mean, we could of course invert the selection and just select those two, instead of explicitly excluding 98(+) others. E.g. in that case, we could use `df.tag_name.isin(['happy','sad'])` rather than `df.tag_name.ne('angry')`

Comment: Ahhh thank you so much! I will have to test it out